# Unirest POST call mocking - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mockito, powermock, unirest

I am calling an API with following lines of codes using Unirest

```
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("/upstream_url").
                field("username", username).
                field("password", password).
                field("grant_type", "password").
                field("client_id", getSSOClientId()).
                field("client_secret", getClientSecret())).
                asJson();
        return response;
```

When I tried to mock this call I keep getting NPE at field call. Has anyone done mocking such Multipart Unirest post call?

In my test class I have mocked this call as follows:

```
        httpRequestWithBody = Mockito.mock(HttpRequestWithBody.class);
        httpRequestWithBody.field("username", "username@userdomin.com");
        httpRequestWithBody.field("password", "***");
        httpRequestWithBody.field("grant_type", "password");
        httpRequestWithBody.field("client_id", "xyz");
        httpRequestWithBody.field("client_secret", "xxdf-112-ddfg");
        String requestStr = "upstream_url";

        Mockito.when(Unirest.post(requestStr + "/")).thenReturn(httpRequestWithBody);
        Mockito.when(httpResponse.getStatus()).thenReturn(Integer.valueOf(200));
```

The post call itself is still returning null.